# Manipulate string to convert it to another string with different format

Tags: php, string

I have a string in the following form:

```
$my_original_string = "A value1,A value2,E value3,A value4";
```

The first letter is a sort of label, the value is associated with a label.

I must manipulate and convert my string to the following:

```
$my_converted_string = "A: value1 value2 value4, E: value3";
```

With a simple loop, I created an array $temp:

```
$my_original_string = "A value1,A value2,E value3,A value4";

$original_string_to_array = explode(",", $my_original_string);
$o_len = count($original_string_to_array);

$temp = [];

for($i=0; $i<$o_len; $i++){
    $temp[explode(" ",$original_string_to_array[$i])[0]][] = explode(" ",$original_string_to_array[$i])[1];
}

print_r($temp);

/*
Result:

Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [0] => value1
            [1] => value2
            [2] => value4
        )

    [E] => Array
        (
            [0] => value3
        )

)
*/
```

Starting from here, I could eventually loop again to build my new string. Or maybe I could do it even in one loop.

But, **is there anything better I could do?** I checked the capabilities of `array_map`, `array_filter` and `array_walk` but I could not find a way to apply them in this particular case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use `implode()` to turn an array into a comma-separated string.

Comment: You can't use `array_map()` because it only gets the values, not the keys. So use a `foreach()` loop to push each key and the imploded values into another array, then implode that to get the final result.

Comment: @Barmar: no problem for implode. What I was searching for was a solution without a loop and I felt this was not possible (you confirmed this too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of coding improvements would reduce some of the code, using a `foreach` instead of the `for` (where you also have to count the items).  Also inside the loop, use `explode()` once to reduce repetition of the code.

This also inside the loop checks if the key is already present.  If it is, it just appends the new value, if it isn't it creates a new value with the key and value. When it outputs the value, it uses `implode()` to stick the values back together...

```
$my_original_string = "A value1,A value2,E value3,A value4";

$originalArray = explode(",", $my_original_string);
$output = [];
foreach($originalArray as $item )   {
    [$key, $value] = explode(" ", $item, 2);
    $output[$key] = (isset($output[$key])) ? $output[$key]." ".$value 
                        : "$key: $value";
}
print_r(implode(", ", $output));
```

gives...

```
A: value1 value2 value4, E: value3
```

Comment: Ok, that's fine, but it confirms there's no solution without a loop   :-)

Comment: Even the `array_` functions are effectively a loop - and are sometime less efficient.  There may be another way to do it, but I tend to go for readability than something that may look neat (most of the time).

Comment: What's the point of making `$output` an associative array? `implode()` doesn't use the keys.

Comment: @Barmar, so you can add the value to the correct list (a list of the values for `A` or `E`).

Comment: @NigelRen Of course, I don't actually hate loops, even if sometimes I tend to prefer readibility over performance, expecially when the code efficiency isn't that important  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use [array_map](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$string = "A value1,A value2,E value3,A value4,B value5";

$split = explode(',', $string);
$walk = array();
$map = array_map(function($a) use(&$walk) {
  list($key,$value) = explode(' ',$a);
  $walk[$key] = (isset($walk[$key]) ?
                sprintf('%s %s',$walk[$key],$value)
                : sprintf('%s: %s',$key,$value));
  return $walk;
}, $split);

$str = implode(',',array_pop($map));
echo $str;
```

return output with :

```
A: value1 value2 value4,B: value5,E: value3
```

or in array

```
Array
(
    [A] => A: value1 value2 value4
    [B] => B: value5
    [E] => E: value3
)
```

Note: if you use `$map` you need to use `array_pop` to get last element, also you can use `$walk` if you don't like to use `array_pop`